Problem 2.14 from Isaacs's Character Theory of Finite Group
I'm solving this problem from Isaacs's Character Theory of Finite Group:

Let $H \subseteq G' \cap Z(G)$ be cyclic of order $n$ and let $m$ be the maximum of the orders of the elements of $G/H$. Assume that $n$ is a prime power and show that $|G| \geq n^2m$.

With its hint:

Choose $\chi \in$ Irr($G$) with $H \cap ker \chi =1$. Let $\lambda=det \chi$, i.e. $\lambda(g)=det\phi(g)$, a representation $\phi$ with character $\chi$. Then $\chi_H=\chi(1)\mu,\mu \in $Irr($H$). Using $\lambda$ and $\mu$ show that $\chi(1) \geq n$. Then using $\chi(1)\leq |G/H|$ to finish.

However,I couldn't work out how $\lambda$ act in this problem, and why we can find a $\mu$ s.t. $\chi_H=\chi(1)\mu$. Any hint or solution would be helpful, thanks a lot.

I will show that $n\leq\chi(1)$.
Since $n$ is a $p$-power for some prime $p$, if $H\cap\ker\chi\not=1$ for every $\chi\in\text{Irr}(G)$ then it would follow that $K\subseteq H\cap\ker\chi$ for the only subgroup $K$ of $H$ which has order $p$. But this is not possible as $\cap_{\chi\in\text{Irr}(G)}\ker\chi=1$. Then we may take $\chi\in\text{Irr} (G)$ with $H\cap\ker\chi=1$.
Now, as $H\subseteq\textbf{Z}(G)\subseteq\textbf{Z}(\chi)$ it follows that $\chi_H=\chi(1)\mu$ for some $\mu\in\text{Lin}(H)$, as we may write $\chi_{\textbf{Z}(\chi)}=\chi(1)\varphi$ for some $\varphi\in\text{Lin}(\textbf{Z}(\chi))$. It suffices to take $\mu=\varphi_H$. Also, notice that $\ker\mu=1$.
Consider now $\lambda=\det\chi$. Then, $\lambda_H=(\det\chi)_H=\det(\chi_H)=\mu^{\chi(1)}$. But as $G'=\cap_{\theta\in\text{Lin}(G)}\ker\theta$, $H\subseteq G'$ and $\det\chi\in\text{Lin}(G)$ we obtain that $\mu^{\chi(1)}=1_H$.
Since the order of $\mu$ in $\text{Lin}(H)$ is $o(\mu)=|H:\ker\mu|=|H|=n$ and $\mu^{\chi(1)}=1_H$ we deduce that $n\leq\chi(1)$.

Oh,I get it,thanks a lot!
